# joomla Initialise the application doesn't work

Tags: php, joomla

I am in need of real help!
My site ran into a problem and I move it to local for testing the functions
and I get some point that it can not initialise the application.

```
echo " hello 2 ";
// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();
echo " hello 3 ";

// Mark afterIntialise in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;
echo " hello 4 ";

// Route the application.
$app->route();
echo " hello 5 ";

// Mark afterRoute in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRoute') : null;

// Dispatch the application.
$app->dispatch();
echo " hello 6 ";
```

In **index.php** in Joomla if I comment out `$app->initialise();` then it echos **hello 3** but still doesn't go to **hello 5**
any idea??

Comment: Are you seeing any kind of php errors show up in the browser?

Comment: Somewhere is error. Insert at the beginning: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`. I think you don't edit path configs

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to edit the root *index.php*? If you need any core functionality, use a plugin as this is what they're there for. What you're currently doing now is the first step to screwing up your site

Comment: i got 500 http server internal error i and found no mistake with my server.then i decided to test it to find out the bug.

Comment: Set error reporting to maximum in your Joomla configuration. Then an error will be shown on the site instead of a blank page with a 500 error. Let us know what for an error message will be shown.